# Getting and array of values from an array of CustomObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I have the following issue, I need to get an array of values from an array of custom Objects. Is there a method for doing this without iterating the principal array, let me graphic it a little bit.

```
NSArray *principalArray = @[
         customObject1,customObject2,customObject3,....customObject(n)
];
```

This customObject instances have a properties lets say **id,name,lastname**. 
I want to get an NSArray with the value of **name** from the `principalArray`

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

As somebody pointed out in comments: its a duplicate of existing SO question: [Getting an NSArray of a single attribute from an NSArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968702/getting-an-nsarray-of-a-single-attribute-from-an-nsarray)

There is a method for `NSArray - valueForKey` - with key being an attribute of your first array. This method returns you an NSArray from an NSArray.

In your case you can do the following:

```
NSArray *nameArray = [principalArray valueForKey:@"name"];
```